# Design a login form so IE will remember login data

Tags: html, internet-explorer, authentication, internet-explorer-7

My company website, which I develop, requires a login using a form.

Firefox correctly asks for and remembers login details, but test instances of IE6, IE7 do not remember either the username or password, and IE8 will give a dropdown of usernames previously used, but will not remember the password.

- What is it about the design of my password form that allows or prevents IE from prompting?
- Can I alter the design of my page so IE will remember username/password form data (assuming the user has their preferences set correctly)?
- Is there some magic HTML tag, name, or style I should be using?

Comment: This would be great for "superuser" (when it arrives) - but it doesn't seem programming related.

Comment: It is programming related, I'm asking how I can make this happen in IE... with code. I need to know what triggers this in IE and what I'm missing in my HTML.

Comment: Unfortunately there's not enough information in this question to know if it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621596/ie-not-offering-to-save-password-of-asp-net-form or not.  It might be, but hopefully others will know if there are other cases where IE won't save form data.

Answer (score 1):

You might try looking into DOM storage to store username/password persistently on the client side. It'll require JavaScript though and won't work in older versions of IE.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the site(s) you're trying to access to the "Local Intranet" zone, rather than the "Internet" zone.  (assuming this won't cause you security worries)

Tools/Options/Security/Intranet/Sites/Advanced --> add your site(s) here.  In my experience, by putting them in the more highly trusted "Intranet" zone my passwords are remembered.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in this case, also we couldn't possibly ask all of our users to do this. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the input box for the password is set as an input type of password?

One thought I had was to explore the naming convention of your form and input fields.  Perhaps IE is looking for certain combinations to know that this is a login form that it can offer to save the login credentials for.  Also, I have noticed that some web technologies/languages read different elements to get the field names. You might need to set your input fieldnames using both "id" and "name" to get everything to work.

Answer (score 0):

Does your IE remember passwords for other sites than your company website?

Just want to make sure you have not disabled password storage in your IE.