# IE not offering to save password of ASP.NET form

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, webforms, passwords

Sometimes Microsoft does something so stunningly dumb that it makes my head hurt. Help me find out it's really not the case ... please!

I've got an issue with the login page of an ASP.NET (3.5) site I'm developing whereby IE (7 or 8 ... can't bear to open 6) doesn't offer to save the password when a user logs in. I've checked other browsers and Firefox, Chrome and Safari all offer to save the password just fine. I've also confirmed that IE password saving on my test boxes is is working OK on other sites and for e.g. Google etc it works fine.

The searching I've done has turned up very little, but what little it did turn up seems to suggest that IE won't offer to save a password if the form on the page contains more than two text controls. That's the case with my form which also has controls to allow a user to register. And when I remove these additional controls, IE magically prompts to save password, so this does seem to be true.

Now ... if ASP.NET would allow me to have multiple forms, all would be well and I would be able to separate out the two functions into standalone forms and IE would prompt to save passwords. But, ASP.NET doesn't allow me to do this as it only allows a single form. I could fudge a non runat=server form in there and try to do this, but guess what? Because my page uses a MasterPage, any form tag I add is automatically stripped out, even if it's a non runat=server form.

So, I don't see any way around this without fundamentally changing what I was trying to achieve. It looks like I have to explain to my users that they won't be prompted to have their passwords saved if they use IE (a Microsoft product) because I developed my site with ASP.NET (err ... a Microsoft product).

If this is so, I just can't get over how head-smackingly ridiculous this is. If anyone can offer any ideas on how to get around it, can tell me I've got it all wrong and am a big, stupid idiot myself, or just wants to confirm that it's not just me that thinks this is monumentously dumb, then please, please do so.

Just for the record, I really don't want to (and don't see why I should have to) compromise my design and split my pages in two (which will result in a worse experience for the user).

Comment: Curious design decision on MS's part.  No idea what the motivation there is.  As for your design... Why not just offer to keep the user logged in if you're convinced that password-saving is a deal-breaker for users?  Or do you do this also?

Comment: Yeah, I think that's going to be my only option, I was just hoping for confirmation of that behaviour as there's very little I've been able to find on it. And, as you say, it's a curious one.

It's not so much that password-saving is a deal breaker, just hard to explain to anyone that might ask why it's not possible and why Microsoft platform + Microsoft browser = Fail, in this particular case.

Comment: Have you tried using raw HTML text boxes with a form which submits back to an aspx page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Chris That's what I went for in the end.

So for the benefit of anyone else, I still have my activation controls in a runat=server form and process these in the code for that page. Then I have a second, standard HTML form with HTML input textfields that posts to a different .NET page. This deals with the users login. I pick up the values in this page via Request.Form and deal with the login from here.

**Upsides:**

It all works and users get their logins remembered as they would expect to.

**Downsides:**

I lost the ability to use a MasterPage (as I need two forms in the page) so I effectively have had to duplicate the template - I don't like this much.

If the users login is invalid or causes some kind of error, I have to redirect to the initial page and pass it a flag to get it to show a relevant error message - I don't like this much either.

Like I say, though, it just works and in this case that's what was most important. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Why not just add some javascript to the page that runs when the login button is clicked that removes the other textboxes from the page?

Comment: You can use a MasterPage and have content outside of the ASPX form tag.  It can be dificult to work in certain layouts, but if you can use absolute or relative positioning then maybe not too bad.  You just need to place a content place holder on the master page that is outside of the form tag, either above or below, and then place the content control for it in your content page.  A good example of that, which you've probably already used, is placing one in the head section to add script/style in a content page.