# IE not offering to save passwords on my login page

Tags: asp.net, html, internet-explorer, authentication

I'm developing a basic login page in ASP.NET.
The page includes an email field, a password field and a submit button.
For some reason Internet Explorer doesn't offer to remember the login info, while other browsers such as Firefox & Chrome do.
For other pages (Gmail, Twitter etc.) IE als offers to remember password.
Please note that I am not using a username that I previously asked IE not to remember the password for.

Basically, how does IE recognize a login page, and why won't it recognize mine as such?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966512/design-a-login-form-so-ie-will-remember-login-data

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem while developing simple login form which submits itself by tag `<a>` instead of `<input type="submit">`. But the form was not developed under ASP.NET (which i do not know what is).

The problem was solved thank to the following article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/09/11/troubleshooting-stored-login-problems-in-ie.aspx

The article discusses main prolems with occurence of "remember password" dialog in IE. My case was number 5 in that article. I inserted AutoCompleteSaveForm() method before submit() one and IE started to display the dialog.
Breafly speaking, the incorrect form code was:

```
<form action='javascript:void(0)' method='post' id="form_id" >
<input type="text" id="login_text" /><br/>
<input type="password" id="password" /><br/>
<a href="#" onclick="submit()"> Login </a>
<form/>
```

The correct one was:

```
<form action='javascript:void(0)' method='post' id="form_id" >
<input type="text" id="login_text" /><br/>
<input type="password" id="password" /><br/>
<a href="#" onclick="window.external.AutoCompleteSaveForm(document.getElementById('form_id')); document.getElementById('form_id').submit();"> Login </a>
<form/>
```

Hope this helps.

Best Regards,
Ilya.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is quite old but I was running into this same problem. My issue was that I had converted the Login control to a template and because of styling concerns I changed the default asp:Button to an asp:LinkButton.

Internet Explorer apparently looks for an `<input>` tag in order to save passwords. The link button renders an `<a>` tag so IE wasn't recognizing my Login control as a valid login form.

Hope this helps!